# Inordinately slow Nested Loop with join on simple query

Tags: postgresql

I'm running the query below against the primary key lt_id (no other index bar the pkey btree) and joining against 1000 ids.
It might be just my lack of experience with postgres but it seems like it's maybe an order of magnitude slow.. There are 800k rows in the table in total.

This is a low spec machine(4G mem) but still thought it should be faster. CPU is idle.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) SELECT lt_id FROM "mytable" d INNER JOIN ( VALUES (1839147),(...998 more rows here...),(1756908)) v(id) ON (d.lt_id = v.id);

                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..7743.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=69.852..20743.393 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2395 read=1607
   ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..4.770 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using lt_id_idx on mytable d  (cost=0.42..7.73 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=20.732..20.732 rows=1 loops=1000)
         Index Cond: (lt_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
         Heap Fetches: 1000
         Buffers: shared hit=2395 read=1607
 Planning Time: 86.284 ms
 Execution Time: 20744.223 ms
(9 rows)
```

psql 11.7 , I was using 9 but upgraded to 11.7 , no real difference in speed observed.

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3783732      158076     3400932       55420      224724     3366832
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Even though it's low spec should it really be taking 20 seconds? In fact many other queries are taking twice as long or more. 20 seconds seems to be the best case scenario. There are a couple of other text columns in the table with some small text articles which I doubt is the issue.

I was previously using IN operator but observed similar or worse speeds.
I also made a couple of small changes from the default config, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.
work_mem = 32MB
shared_buffers = 512MB

Any ideas if this is expected performance given the machine? Or is there something else I can try?

edit: I guess what I'm curious about it the time in the actual loop
actual time=20.732..20.732 rows=1 loops=1000

It seems like the actual time is less than or equal 1ms per loop which in worst case would be less than 1 second for 1000 iterations and other operations also seem negligible. Does this mean the issue is simple IO ? slow disk ? What would typically be the situation here. 
I notice if I run the query on my desktop which only has 8G ram but is using an SSD the query is massively faster..
Using an SSD is fine of course but I'd like to know if something in my config or query/setup is not optimal..

Comment: To know how much time is spent doing I/O can you try to enable io timing in PG with `track_io_timing=on` and re-run your statements with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)`

Comment: See also other sites like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/postgresql-force-data-into-memory/2044#2044 instead of Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks !! IO timings confirms it. updated query. So simply.. slow disk then.. it might be the VM setup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @pifor suggested, set track_io_timing=on , can see that this is indeed almost entirely IO slowness..

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..7743.00 rows=1000 width=69) (actual time=0.026..14901.004 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2859 read=1145
   I/O Timings: read=14861.578
   ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.002..5.497 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable d  (cost=0.42..7.73 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=14.888..14.888 rows=1 loops=1000)
         Index Cond: (lt_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
         Buffers: shared hit=2859 read=1145
         I/O Timings: read=14861.578
 Planning Time: 0.420 ms
 Execution Time: 14901.734 ms
(10 rows)
```